# How to remove complete entries based on variable in another column

Tags: r, subset

I want to remove the rows in the data frame that correspond to location = 2, 4 and out. See data below.

```
date <- c("2016-03-24","2016-03-24","2016-03-24","2016-03-24","2016-03-24",
      "2016-03-24","2016-03-24","2016-03-24","2016-03-24","2016-03-24")
location <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,"out","out")
sensor <- c(1,16,1,16,1,16,1,16,1,16)
Temp <- c(35,34,92,42,21,47,37,42,63,12)
df <- data.frame(date,location,sensor,Temp)
```

Comment: `df[!df$location %in% c(2, 4, "out"), ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

`df_new = df[!df$location %in% c("2","4","out"),]`